Should [java-platform-module-system] be merged into [java-module]?
The 2 tags java-platform-module-system and java-module seem to capture the exact same type of questions, but the second one is far easier to find and more intuitive to use.
I should add, a lot of the questions just add both. That is a good indicator that the users of these tags don't see the difference either, and just want to ask a question about modules in general.

The excerpt of java-module also reads: "A module in the Java Platform Module System", so this seems like a great indicator that they are about the same concept. Not sure whether a synonym would be better instead of a merge. I don't really know the rule of thumb though in such cases where there seems to be no misuse.

@Lino I vote merge, as this topic is notoriously difficult for users, and therefore, having only one tag to search for would be helpful. Having to go through the combinations of a, b, then ab is what I want to avoid by doing a merge.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but a merge is not going to prevent the unwanted tag from reappearing, it is only going to temporarily remove the eye sore.

A merge will delete the tag and require a user with 1500 rep to recreate it. Which significantly reduces the chance of it recurring. @Gimby Now a merge plus a synonym would also prevent it from being recreated since it already exists and remaps to a target.

@HenryEcker very informative, I was unaware of that 1500 rep condition. That's actually... great.

@HenryEcker That's very clever, ty vm.

Ok, I'm a little ignorant about the process here. Is there some next steps I should take to get a final decision on this? Or is this something where I need to convince someone with the power to do this?

@davidalayachew things don't happen just because a couple of peeps agree on it. So far this post has a net score of 2, that's not very convincing.

@Gimby that's actually what my question was -- what is the next steps here? To me, it sounds like you are saying that enough people have to be convinced by this for any action to occur. And thus, since only a few people have taken interest, it kind of implies that this just isn't that wanted/needed, right?
